# Wordpress - Totally private custom post type. Am I right?

Tags: wordpress

I did write a simple contact form plugin.

I want save in database all the contact received, and of course they need be visible only to the admin, in backend. I need to mantain totally private because contact form contains personal data (mobile phone, email, etc etc).

This is my code. In frontend I cannot see the received forms (perfect, I want this!), I can see them only in backend (perfect). But in frontend, If I recall "http://www.example.com/inbox " Wordpress doesn't redirect to a 404, simply to an archive page of articles. Is it normal? Is it not better than wordpress on frontend redirect them to a 404?

Relevant code:

```
// Registrazione del Post Type
    public function create_post_type() {
        // Etichette del Post Type
        $labels = array(

            // Nome plurale del post type
            'name' => _x( 'Richieste ricevute', 'Post Type General Name', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),

            // Nome singolare del post type
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Form', 'Post Type Singular Name', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),

            // Testo per pulsante Aggiungi
            'add_new' => __( 'Aggiungi', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),

            // Testo per pulsante Tutti gli articoli
            'all_items' => __( 'Tutte le richieste', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),

            // Testo per pulsante Aggiungi nuovo articolo
            //'add_new_item' => __( 'Aggiungi Nuovo Contatto', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),

            // Testo per pulsante Modifica
            'edit_item' => __( 'Modifica', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),

            // Testo per pulsante Nuovo
            'new_item' => __( 'Nuovo', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),

            // Testo per pulsante Visualizza
            'view_item' => __( 'Dettaglio', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),

            // Testo per pulsante Cerca articoli
            'search_items' => __( 'Cerca', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),

            // Testo per nessun articolo trovato
            'not_found' => __( 'Nessun risultato', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),

            // Testo per nessun articolo trovato nel cestino
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nessun risultato nel cestino', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),

            // Testo per articolo genitore
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Genitore:', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN ),

            // Testo per Menù
            'menu_name' => __( 'Richieste', WPTRESF__PLUGIN_DOMAIN )
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,

            // Descrizione
            'description' => 'Richieste ricevute',

            // Rende visibile o meno da front-end il post type
            'public' => false, // here

            // Esclude o meno il post type dai risultati di ricerca
            'exclude_from_search' => true, // here

            // Rende richiamabile o meno da front-end il post type tramite una query
            'publicly_queryable' => false, // here

            // Rende disponibile l'interfaccia grafica del post type da back-end
            'show_ui' => true,

            // Rende disponibile o meno il post type per il menù di navigazione
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,

            // Definisce dove sarà disponibile l'interfaccia grafica del post type nel menù di amministrazione
            'show_in_menu' => true,

            // Rende disponibile o meno il post type per l'admin bar di wordpress
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true,

            // La posizione nel menù
            'menu_position' => 20,

            // L'icona del post type nel menù
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-comments',

            // I permessi che servono per editare il post type
            'capability_type' => 'post',

            // ADD / EDIT SECTION

            'capabilities' => array(
                'create_posts' => false, // Removes support for the "Add New" function ( use 'do_not_allow' instead of false for multisite set ups )
            ),
            'map_meta_cap' => true, // Set to `false`, if users are not allowed to edit/delete existing posts

            // Definisce se il post type è gerarchico o meno
            'hierarchical' => true,

            // I meta box che il post type supporta nell'interfaccia di editing
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes' ),

            // Le tassonomie supportate dal post type
            'taxonomies' => array( 'contact_form' ),

            // Definisce se il post type ha o meno un archivio
            'has_archive' => true,

            // Imposta lo slug del post type
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'inbox', 'with_front' => false ),
        );
                // Registra il Custom Post Type
        register_post_type( WPTRESF__CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_NAME , $args );
    }
```